# Ionic2 - Constructor and Page Lifecycles called multiple times

Tags: ionic2

I have some piece of code in my app that should be executed only once on my page, but it seems all of my page lifecycles and the constructor are called multiple times (every x seconds it's called once). I don't have that same problem on my HomePage, for example. Any ideas? The component and module are like this:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPageModule } from 'ionic-angular';
import { ChamadaAtendimento } from './chamada-atendimento';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    ChamadaAtendimento,
  ],
  imports: [
    IonicPageModule.forChild(ChamadaAtendimento),
  ],
  exports: [
    ChamadaAtendimento
  ]
})
export class ChamadaAtendimentoModule {}
```

This is the component:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPage } from 'ionic-angular';
import { NavParams, NavController, ModalController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { ApiService } from '../../providers/api-service';
import { DialogService } from '../../providers/dialog-service';
import { AuthService } from '../../providers/auth-service';
import { HomePage } from '../home/home';
import { SetMotivoIntervalo } from '../set-motivo-intervalo/set-motivo-intervalo';
import { Platform } from "ionic-angular";
import { NativeAudio } from '@ionic-native/native-audio';

@IonicPage()
@Component({
  selector: 'page-chamada-atendimento',
  templateUrl: 'chamada-atendimento.html',
})
export class ChamadaAtendimento {

  chamada_id : number;
    area : string = "";
    atividade : string = "";
  resposta_enviada : boolean = false;

  constructor(
    navParams: NavParams,
    private nav: NavController,
    private api: ApiService,
    private dialog: DialogService,
    private auth: AuthService,
    private platform: Platform,
    private nativeAudio: NativeAudio,
    private modalCtrl: ModalController
  ) {

    this.chamada_id = navParams.data.chamada_id;
    this.area = navParams.data.area;
    this.atividade = navParams.data.atividade;

    if (this.platform.is('cordova')) {
      this.nativeAudio.preloadSimple('chamada', 'assets/sounds/Umbriel.mp3');
      this.nativeAudio.loop('chamada');
    }

  }


  ionViewWillEnter(){
    console.log("page lifecycle test");
  }


  responderChamada(resposta){

    console.log("resposta ",resposta),
    console.log("resp enviada",this.resposta_enviada);
    if(!this.resposta_enviada){

      this.resposta_enviada = true;

      if (this.platform.is('cordova')) {
        this.nativeAudio.stop('chamada');
        this.nativeAudio.unload('chamada');
      }

      if(resposta=="Intervalo"){
        const modal = this.modalCtrl.create(SetMotivoIntervalo, {chamada_id: this.chamada_id});
        modal.present();
      }else{
        this.dialog.showLoading("Enviando resposta...");
        this.api.responder_chamada(this.chamada_id, resposta).subscribe(
            () => {
            this.dialog.loading.dismiss();
            this.auth.setStatusAtual(resposta);
            if (resposta=="Atendimento"){
              this.auth.setChamada(this.chamada_id, this.area, this.atividade);
            }else{
              this.nav.setRoot(HomePage);
            }

            if(resposta=="Inativo"){
              this.dialog.showToast("Status de Operação definido como Inativo");
            }else{
              this.dialog.showToast("Resposta enviada com sucesso");
            }

            },(error) =>{
            this.dialog.loading.dismiss();
            if(error && error.length){
              this.dialog.showAlert("Erro ao responder chamada", error);
            }
            }
        );
      }

    }

  }


  encerrarAtendimento(){
    this.dialog.showLoading("Encerrando atendimento...");
    this.api.encerrar_atendimento(this.chamada_id).subscribe(
      () => {
        this.dialog.loading.dismiss();
        this.auth.setChamada(null, null, null);
        this.nav.setRoot(HomePage);
        this.dialog.showToast("Atendimento encerrado com sucesso");
      },(error) => {
        this.dialog.loading.dismiss();
        if(error && error.length){
          this.dialog.showAlert("Erro ao encerrar atendimento", error);
        }
      }
    );
  }

}
```

Comment: How do you know your constructor is called many times?

Comment: @Duannx in this code I pasted, my console.log is on ionViewWillEnter, but also tried on the constructor. Anyway, got my answer... gonna post it here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got my answer:
I had a `setInterval` on my `app.component`, which called a function every x seconds. Every time that function was called, it seems it alternates the component so it have to re-construct, or something like that, not sure. Anyway, the sollution for me was to `clearInterval` for that page. But still didn't understand quite well what happened

Answer (score 0):

I followed the route to the component and noticed a lack of validation. I put this and it solved the problem.

```
Both codes:
redirect = () => this.navCtrl.setRoot(HomePage);


Old code:
this.redirect();


New code:
if (!this.redirected) {
   this.redirected = true;
   this.redirect();
}
```